# Computing modulus in parallel using bit manipulation

Tags: c, algorithm, language-agnostic, bit-manipulation

The following link is to a bit hack that shows how to compute the modulus by 2^n - 1 in parallel: [ModulusDivisionParallel](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ModulusDivisionParallel)

Can you explain how this bit manipulation works, and how to unroll the loop shown given a specific denominator (see example below, where do the bit masks come from)?

Example of unrolling the loop for 0xF:

```
y = x mod 0xF
y = x & 0x0F0F0F0F + ((x & 0xF0F0F0F0) >> 4)  
y = y & 0x00FF00FF + ((y & 0xFF00FF00) >> 8)  
y = y & 0x0000FFFF + ((y & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16)  
y = y & 0xF
```

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. I am working on optimizing an assembly modulus method, which at the moment uses branches and a mask of the form 2^n-1. So I am trying to get rid of the branches and use this method instead.

Comment: Interesting.  Can I ask what kind of application you have that uses a modulus of 2^n-1?  Is there a reason not to use 2^n or a prime number instead?

Comment: @JS1 It´s not that unusual. One example of many: A byte-wise Reed-Solomon code (data error recognition and correction), and Galois field based algorithms in general. The encoding (of RS) is fairy simple code-wise, it consists mainly of loops, additions, and modulo (given that some static data is calculated in advance, instead of each time during decoding)

Comment: @deviantfan Thanks, you learn something new every day!

Comment: @deviantfan Nice examples!

Comment: @JS1 The method that I am changing is being used on the Mozilla Firefox JavaScript JIT Compiler -> http://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/js/src/jit/arm/MacroAssembler-arm.cpp#914

Comment: The first iteration has streaks of bits of length n, the next one of length 2n and so on. The method works by summing digits in base 2^n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a clarification:

When `s = 4` (that is, the modulus is equal to `0xF`) I get the following unrolling:

```
m = (n & 0x0F0F0F0F) + ((n >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F)
m = ((n >> 16) + (n & 0x0000FFFF)
m = ((n >>  8) + (n & 0x000000FF)
m = ((n >>  4) + (n & 0x0000000F)
m = ((n >>  4) + (n & 0x0000000F)
m = ((n >>  4) + (n & 0x0000000F)
m = ((n >>  4) + (n & 0x0000000F)
m = m == 0xF ? 0 : m;
```

This is very different than what you have in your question. To explain why this works:

Ever heard of the math trick where if you add up all the digits of a number and it's divisible by 9 then the original number is, too? That works because the remainders of dividing both the original and the sum by 9 is the same. Actually, that's what we're doing here, just in a different base -- in your example, with hexadecimal base.

The math kung-fu is this:

Each hexadecimal digit's contribution to the final value can be represented as `V * 16 ^ P`. Note that `16 ^ P = 1 (mod 15)`, so each hexadecimal digit's contribution to the final value is simply `V (mod 15)`. In other words, to get the total contribution from all the digits, add them all up `(mod 15)`.

The bitwise operations are just a clever way of doing this in logarithmic number of steps: repeatedly add the first half of the hexadecimal digits to the second half.

The problem with the 9's trick is you might end up with a two digit number: 99 = 9 + 9 = 18 (mod 10)! Then you just do the trick again: 18 = 1 + 8 = 9 (mod 10).

Likewise, we follow up with 'extra' iterations of `m = ((n >>  4) + (n & 0x0000000F)` until the remaining number is one digit.

Now the only remaining detail is if we get `0xF` as the result in which case we want `0x0` instead.